# Jquery Iterating over flask sqlalchemy query all results passed to html template as parameter

Tags: jquery, html, flask

I'm trying to use jquery to iterate over flask sqlalchemy query.all() results that I pass to template as a parameter. I have db schema as:
customer table: id, name, phone

Customers in db are:

1 Smith 1111111111

2 Jones 2222222222

3 Edwards 3333333333

Flask view:

```
@auth.route('/orders/add', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def order_add():
  custs = Customer.query.all()
  return render_template('auth/orders/order_add.html', custs=custs, form=form)
```

html code:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12">
  <label class="control-label" for="cust_name">Company Name</label>
  <input class="form-control" id="cust_name" name="cust_name" type="text" list="customers" />
  <datalist id="customers">
  </datalist>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
$('#cust_name').keyup(function() {
  var cust = "{{ custs }}"
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    cust.each(function(i, name, pn) {
      alert(name);
      alert(pn);
    });
  }
});
```

I can't figure out how to iterate over these results like FOR...EACH did in the old templating code:

```
<datalist id="customers">
  {% FOR cust IN custs %}
    <option>{{ cust.name }}</option>
  {% ENDFOR %}
</datalist>
```

I have tried:

```
alert(cust.name); - didn't work
alert(cust[0]); - didn't work
alert({{ custs.name }}); - didn't work
alert("{{ cust.name }}"); - didn't work
```

even tried:

```
$('#comp_name').keyup(function() {
  var comp = '{{ comps }}';
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    alert(comp.length);
  }
});
```

Alert shows 80, I still can't figure that one out either!

In case your wondering what my ultimate goal is, once I get this code to work, I'm creating a document fragment and adding the cust.name to the datalist select using only jquery!

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this, setup an Ajax call back to db.